# Rewrite rule to add characters to beginning of urls in nginx where they are missing

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm working on a legacy site where all urls must begin with the single available language code '/en'.

Is it possible with nginx to rewrite urls that do not begin with '/en' so that it is added (the legacy application will then be able to find the content and serve it)?

E.g.

```
  http://www.example.com/         ->  http://www.example.com/en/
  http://www.example.com/page1    ->  http://www.example.com/en/page1
  http://www.example.com/en/page1 ->  http://www.example.com/en/page1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. It's a bit difficult to give you a full solution since you haven't provided the config file, but I'll give it a shot.

You're looking for something along the lines of:

```
if ($request_uri !~ "^/en.*"){
    return 301 $scheme://www.example.com/en$uri;
}
```

Note: This should appear immediately after your `server_name` and `listen` directives and not in a `location` block ([see here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/)).

I hope this helps.